# Using html buttons as radio input label

Tags: html

I want to have radio input choice done with pushing buttons. (it's where you have several options and you can only choose one,  usually done with radio dots) 
 I used

```html
    <input id="test"><label for="test">Click Me</label>
```

To achieve the same effect but with text (when clicked on text radio button sets to checked="true", but no matter how I try to approach it while using HTML buttons I never can get radio input checked with just button and not text clicking. 
 So this and variation of this where you set button as parent with for tag etc. didn't work for me.

```html
<input id="test"><label for="test"><button>Click Me</button></label>
```

I can use something like addEventListeners to buttons and set the choice in javascript, but thought maybe there is an obvious pure HTML way I just could not figure out. Heres a [small pen](https://codepen.io/sanchopanza/pen/ZPGLav) just for fiddling around - Cheers

Comment: Also, I thought of using a button with onClick="document....checked = true etc. But I still wonder if there is a pure HTML way

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? Do you only want the radio button to be checked upon clicking the text "Click Me"?

Comment: `<label>` and  `<button>` are interactive tags. Interactive tags cannot be nested within each other. Stick with the first example and style the `<label>` to look like a `<button>`

Comment: zer00ne that sound reasonable and thanks for the comment on nesting.

Comment: kleinfreund I want for example x amount of buttons with only one possible being pressed at the moment.  Basically, I want to be able to set radio checked="true" with standard HTML buttons and no js. And I guess styling labels is one way to approach it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your first example and style the label element to look like a button.

Here is a quick example:

```css
label {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

input:checked + label {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" />
<label for="radio1">Click me</label>
<input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" />
<label for="radio2">Click me</label>
<input id="radio3" name="radio" type="radio" />
<label for="radio3">Click me</label>
```